# How to run C project on msvc 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, project, visual-studio-debugging

I am familiar with running a CPP project on MSVC and debugging there is much comfortable.
Same feature is applicable for C project or not ?

Can anybody please let me know how to start running with a C project on MSVC

Answer (score 1):

Just create a project in usual way and add files with `*.c` extension. By default MSVC looks at extension and runs either `cpp`-compiler or `c` one

Comment: +1. Just as an addition to make it clear to the OP. When creating new project: **New Project > Visual C++ > General > Empty Project**